# Is there any way to update and insert selected inputs to the database? Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have successfully inserted multiple values and now the ***PROBLEM*** is to query, how can I update at the same time **to update the `correct_id` to 1** - How can I update the selected input using the radio button as a reference value.
Here is my UI, on how it was designed.

I have a field name `correct_id` which value needs to be 1 in order to be considered as a correct answer. Please guide me thorougly as this became a challenge to me. I became confused with the query recently thanks!

[image]

> So as you can see I have radio buttons, I need to choose one input or choice to be my answer

Here is my **Model**.

```
public function addQuestion(){
    // Insert questions

    $field_question = array(
        'question'=>$this->input->post('question'),
    );

    $this->db->insert('questions', $field_question);

    // Insert Answers
    $data_answer = $this->input->post('choice[]');


    $value = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < count($data_answer); $i++) {
        $value[$i] = array(
            'answer' => $data_answer[$i],
            'question_id' => $this->db->insert_id(),
        );
    }


    $this->db->insert_batch('answers', $value);

    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

And my **Form** in view

Here I'll precicely show the radio input and its name and value

```
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="checkChoice[]" id="checkChoice" value="1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
            Make this as an Answer
        </label>
</div>
```

And here is the full view form code.

```
<form method="post" id="myForm" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>posts/addQuestion">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">Question</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Question" name="question" id="question" class="form-control" required />
                    </div>

                    <hr>
                    <h5>Create Choices: </h5>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                    <div class="table-responsive">  
                               <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
                                    <tr>  

                                         <td><input type="hidden" name="choiceHid[]" value="0" /></td> 
                                         <td><input type="text" name="choice[]" id="choice" placeholder="Enter your Choice" class="form-control" /> </td>  
                                         <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><span class="iconify" data-icon="ant-design:plus-circle-outlined" data-inline="false"></span> Add Response </button></td>  
                                         <td>
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="checkChoice[]" id="checkChoice" value="1">
                                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                                                        Make this as an Answer
                                                    </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>  

                               </table>  
                          </div>  
                    </div>

                    <hr>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                            <h5> Your Answer: 
                            <input type="hidden" name="txtAnswer" value="0" />
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the Question's Answer" name="answer_choice" id="answer_choice" class="form-control mt-2" /><h5>
                    </div>
                    <hr>

                    <input type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-block btn-info" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, assign a different index random id for each answer radio and text fields (Ex.: choice[n] and checkChoice[n] pair):

```
<input type="text" name="choice[13]" id="choice" placeholder="Enter your Choice" class="form-control" /> </td>  
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="checkChoice[13]" id="checkChoice" value="1">
```

After, use foreach and verify if the checkChoice with the same index that choice in the loop was sent:

```
foreach($data_answer as $index => $value) {
  array_push($value, array(
        'answer' => $value,
        'question_id' => $this->db->insert_id(),
        'correct_id' => ((isset($_POST['checkChoice'][$index])) ? 1 : null)
    ));
}
```

Because now each radio has a different name, radio behaves like a checkbox (allows you to choose more than one). So, you must force a radio behaviour again with a jquery snippet:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
     // When any radio button on the page is selected,
     // then deselect all other radio buttons.
     $('input[type=radio]:checked').not(this).prop('checked', false);
 });
});
```

Comment: hello, why would i still put `[13]` on my input? what if there's different  number?

Comment: In fact, you can use any number (13 used to illustrate the pair situation). It could be a sequential like choice[1], choice[2], choice[3],  choice[n], ... and the same to the its related pair checkChoice[1], checkChoice[2], checkChoice[3], checkChoice[n]. Using the same index in the two related fields, makes possible in the server link the pairs.